# 1 or 2 partitions for 2 op-systems (Windows 7 + Ubuntu)?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

What is recommended: installing Ubuntu in the same partition as Windows 7 - or in a separated one?
Ubuntu says:

Begin the installation
Depending on your previous selections, you can now verify that you have chosen the way in which you would like to install Ubuntu. The installation process will begin when you click the Install Now button.
Ubuntu needs about 4.5 GB to install, so add a few extra GB to allow for your files.
Not sure about this step? Windows users can use the Windows installer, which will install and uninstall Ubuntu in the same way as any other Windows application. It's simpler and completely safe.

What is the advandage (or disadvantage) of installing Ubuntu in a different partition?

Thank you or your help.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you start by simply booting the desktop editions, you may wish to try Ubuntu (unity), gnome edition, and kubuntu (kde), just to see what you like.

Assuming your hardware works and you like ubuntu you would then install.

Ubuntu will need at least 2 partitions, one of swap and one for Ubuntu.

In general I would use a minimum of 10 Gb for the root partition. In general your swap partition should be = to the size of your ram.

I think you are asking about a wubi install, installing alongside windows. wubi has advantages and disadvantages, but is no longer maintained, so you can not use it with 13.04

In general I do not personally like wubi, but if yo like you can use it.

You will want to back up your data and read the installation guides before you install.

See also

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install both operating systems on the same partition.

As a tip:
The easy way to do it is install Windows 7 first, then make some unalocated space, that space is where Ubuntu will be installed. Afther these steps just go install Ubuntu and when it ask you if you want to install clean or along side Windows you chose along side Windows and it will make a partition from that unallocated space.

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaking but with wubi you cannot chose the partition, right? It will be on the same one with Windows, it won't even prompt him to chose a partition, if so then why would he post a question like this?

Answer (score 0):

The best think will be 3 partitions, 2 ntfs and the other one ext4, a ntfs partition will be for windows 7 and the other one for data is where you save your documents, photos, videos, etc. so you can acess from both systems. The ext4 partition will be for ubuntu (if you use windows for change the partitions do it in ntfs and before installing ubuntu in the instaler you can change it to ext4; I recomend that you use at least 40-50 GB for ubuntu and 40-50 GB for Windows 7, de rest for data. (If your computer have between 1 and 3 GB of RAM I recomend you to do and extended partition with a 40gb for ubuntu and 1 GB for swap so the coputer will go quicker).

I've trayed using wubi in the same partition but it dident work really well I wasn't having acses to my win7 documents and some programs didn't work the mach as quicker.

Sorry for my spelling.